# Call marker icon

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I want to check if my google maps marker has a certain image ressource like this:

```
if (marker.getIcon() == BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.imagefile)) {
}
```

But marker.getIcon does not work, so how can I call the icon of a marker?

Answer (score 0):

you can't get the icon, and the equals will not be valid anyway (it's not the same object if you get from BitmapDescriptorFactory.

Anyway, you can try to use String ids for markers instead of icons

Answer (score 0):

You can use a HashMap to store the type of Icon for each Marker that is added to the map.

I just got a simple example working to give the general idea, using a HashMap that maps the Marker ID to the color of the Icon currently set for the Marker.

If you are using custom Drawables, you could use `HashMap<String, Integer>` instead of `HashMap<String, Float>` as I have in this simple example.

If you change the Marker Icon color or Drawable resource, you should also update the HashMap as well.

Class code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    HashMap<String, Float> markerIcons = new HashMap<>();

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    private void setUpMap() {

        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {

            Float markerColor;
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                markerColor = markerIcons.get(marker.getId());
                if (markerColor == BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "HUE_MAGENTA", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                }
                else if (markerColor == BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "HUE_AZURE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                }
                else if (markerColor == BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "HUE_CYAN", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                }


                return false;
            }

        });
        Marker marker = null;
        marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(2, 2)).title("Marker Magenta").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA)));
        markerIcons.put(marker.getId(), BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA);

        marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(3, 3)).title("Marker Azure").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
        markerIcons.put(marker.getId(), BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE);

        marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(4, 4)).title("Marker Cyan").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN)));
        markerIcons.put(marker.getId(), BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN);

    }
}
```

Result after clicking on each Marker:

[image]

[image]

[image]